# How to declare a static array in an array?

Tags: php

My code:

```
class User
    {
        protected static $config = array(
            'expiration'    => 0,       
        );

        protected static $Db;

        protected static $user = array();
                  static::$user['data'] = array();
                  static::$user['meta'] = array();
                  static::$user['controls'] = array();
```

Here I will get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

by complaining this:

```
`static::$user['data'] = array()`
```

How can I declare static::$user['data'] here?

Comment: You can't declare a static variable inside an array. The initial array will be static so you wouldn't need to make its key values static anyway.

Comment: Somewhere in a class method: `self::$user['key'] = array()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static array variable don't need to explicitly make it's key=>value static too, because it will be taken care automatically.

You need to do like this:-

```
self::$user['data'] = array();
self::$user['meta'] = array();
self::$user['controls'] = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have define `$user` as static so you don't need to declare its elements as static again. If you want to initialize it. You can achieve it by method like below:

```
class User
    {
        protected static $config = array(
            'expiration'    => 0,       
        );

        protected static $Db;

        protected static $user = array();        
        public static function get_user()
        {
          self::$user['data'] = array();
          self::$user['meta'] = array();
          self::$user['controls'] = array();
          return self::$user;
        }

}
$user = User::get_user();
var_dump($user);
```

Comment: Slightly confusing, as every time you `get_user`, you'll be clobbering User::$user.

Comment: Its just an example. initialization can be done in other function also.